# Showing list on the page grouped by a field

Tags: jsf

How can I show/present some data like  (manufacturer, color, type), similar to this one:

```
List<Car> list = new ArrayList<>();          
list.add(new Car("ford", "red", "focus"));    
list.add(new Car("opel", "red", "astra"));    
list.add(new Car("opel", "blue", "astra"));    
list.add(new Car("toyota", "red", "camry"));    
list.add(new Car("honda", "blue", "civic"));    
list.add(new Car("BMW", "green", "3"));
```

on a JSF page like:

```
[red]
ford focus
opel astra
toyota camry

[blue]
opel astra
honda civic

[green]
BMW 3
```

I need more detailed explanation.  I do not know the colors that will come form the database. they are unknown and they are based on user input and their are not defined. this is just an example.

UPDATE

```
class Car {

private String name;
private String color;
private String model;


public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getModel() {
    return model;
}

public void setModel(String model) {
    this.model = model;
}

public String getColor() {
    return color;
}

public void setColor(String color) {
    this.color = color;
}
}
```

My view:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
  xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets">
<h:head>
    <title>Facelet Title</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    Hello from Facelets
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <ui:repeat value="#{carBean.groups}" var="entry">
        <h:outputText value ="#{entry}"/>

        <br/>
        <ui:repeat value="asdasdas" var="second">
            #{second} <br/>
            <br/>
        </ui:repeat>


    </ui:repeat>

    <ui:repeat value="#{carBean.carsGroupedByColor.entrySet().toArray()}" var="entry">
        <div>
            Color: #{entry.key}
            <br />
            <ui:repeat value="#{entry.value}" var="car">
                Car name: #{car}
                <br />
            </ui:repeat>
        </div>
    </ui:repeat>



</h:body>
</html>
```

My bean:

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class CarBean implements Serializable {

private Map<String, List<Car>> carsGroupedByColor;
private List<String> groups;
private List<Car> temp;
private List<Car> carsByColor;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {

    List<Car> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Car car = new Car();
    car.setColor("red");
    car.setModel("camry");
    car.setName("redcar1");
    list.add(car);
    Car car1 = new Car();
    car1.setColor("bue");
    car1.setModel("golf");
    car1.setName("bluecar1");
    list.add(car1);
    Car car2 = new Car();
    car2.setColor("red");
    car2.setModel("astra");
    car2.setName("redcar2");
    list.add(car2);

    System.out.println(list);


    groups = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        //         System.out.println(list.get(i).getName());
        //         System.out.println(list.get(i).getColor());
        //        System.out.println(list.get(i).getModel());
        groups.add(list.get(i).getColor());

    }

    Set<String> set = new HashSet<>(groups);
    groups.clear();
    groups.addAll(set);
    carsGroupedByColor = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    Car carx;

    for (int i = 0; i < groups.size(); i++) {
        temp = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int j = 0; j < list.size(); j++) {

            if (groups.get(i).equals(list.get(j).getColor())) {
                carx = new Car();
                carx.setColor(list.get(j).getColor());
                carx.setName(list.get(j).getName());
                carx.setModel(list.get(j).getModel());

                System.out.println("Color is " + groups.get(i) + "=" + list.get(j).getColor());
                System.out.println(list.get(j).getName());
                temp.add(carx);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(temp);
        carsGroupedByColor.put(groups.get(i), temp);
        System.out.println("carsGroupedByColorcars is " + carsGroupedByColor.get(groups.get(i)));

        System.out.println("temp is clear: " + temp);

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < groups.size(); i++) {

        System.out.println(groups.get(i) + "   " + carsGroupedByColor.get(groups.get(i)));



    }
}

public Map<String, List<Car>> getCarsGroupedByColor() {
    return carsGroupedByColor;
}

public void setCarsGroupedByColor(Map<String, List<Car>> carsGroupedByColor) {
    this.carsGroupedByColor = carsGroupedByColor;
}

public List<String> getGroups() {
    return groups;
}

public void setGroups(List<String> groups) {
    this.groups = groups;
}
}
```

Comment: I remove the [jsf-2.2] tag because this question **it is not directly related to** a specific JSF 2.2 feature/issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a `Map<String, List<Car>>` and iterate your main `List<Car> allCars` to distribute the cars accordingly in the map (I'm assuming `Car#color` is a `String`, otherwise use the right type as the map key).

Java code:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class CarBean {

    private Map<String, List<Car>> carsGroupedByColor;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        List<Car> allCars = ...; //this can be replaced to retrieve the list the way you want/need
        Map<String, List<Car>> carsGroupedByColor = new LinkedHashMap<String, List<Car>>();
        for (Car car : allCars) {
            List<Car> carsByColor = carsGroupedByColor.get(car.getColor());
            if (carsByColor == null) {
                carsByColor = new ArrayList<Car>();
            }
            carsByColor.add(car);
        }
    }

    public Map<String, List<Car>> getCarsGroupedByColor() {
        return carsGroupedByColor;
    }
}
```

Facelets code:

```html
<ui:repeat value="#{carBean.carsGroupedByColor}" var="entry">
    <div>
        Color: #{entry.key}
        <br />
        <ui:repeat value="#{entry.value}" var="car">
            Car name: #{car.name}
            <br />
        </ui:repeat>
    </div>
</ui:repeat>
```

Comment: +1 For a more complete code example then the one I posted. Though, according to the "new requirement" the "color" is actually an unknown property which can be defined by the user, so you can't use `car.getColor()` cause there's no such method. You can generalize and call it `userDefinedProperty()` or something like that

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I have a trouble creating Map<String, List<Car>> carsGroupedByColor or there is something wrong with the code.

Comment: @Pavel I do understand the functional requirement, what I don't understand is where you store the color of the car. If you don't, then think on a strategy to do it.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza You can see the updated post. This what I have right now.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserverfaces/2.2/vdldocs/facelets/ui/repeat.html according to this map is not supported. I tried to make it an array, but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
HashMap<String, List> cars = new HashMap<String, List>();

List<Car> red = new ArrayList<>();
List<Car> blue = new ArrayList<>();
List<Car> green = new ArrayList<>();          
red .add(new Car("ford", "red", "focus"));    
red .add(new Car("opel", "red", "astra"));    
blue.add(new Car("opel", "blue", "astra"));    
red .add(new Car("toyota", "red", "camry"));    
blue.add(new Car("honda", "blue", "civic"));    
green.add(new Car("BMW", "green", "3"));

cars.put("red",red);
cars.put("blue",blue);
cars.put("green",green);

//now it's easy to print them by color ;)
System.out.println("[red]");
for(Car car:(List)cars.get("red"))
    System.out.println(car.getColor());
//etc
```

Comment: This works if you know the list. I can do that. what about if I do not know the colors that come from the database?

Comment: @Pavel then check the `color` before you add the `car` to the correct list respectively. What's even nicer in the above approach, is that you can do something like this: `cars.get(car.getColor()).add(car)`

Comment: I get unknown number of colors. How to show unknown number of lists on the JSF page. The other thing is that I would like the user to add anything to the field as color. This was just an example. This has to work for another case.

Comment: You have an unknown number of colors and you want to display the objects sorted by that unknown property ? You'll have to add another layer of abstraction...